# Sample Google Calendar API - Pure Java

Tags: java, google-api-java-client

I'm trying to setup a basic example that is documented here http://goo.gl/9WudGn

I can't seem to run the application without getting one error or another.

There are no error before I run it, but when I do I get the following runtime error.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mortbay/jetty/Handler
    at com.azinky.CalendarSample.authorize(CalendarSample.java:95)
    at com.azinky.CalendarSample.main(CalendarSample.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mortbay.jetty.Handler
```

I then include two jar files in my classpath, **jetty-6.1.26.jar** and **jetty-util-6.1.26.jar**

Now I get another error at runtime

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest
    at com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver.getRedirectUri(LocalServerReceiver.java:98)
    at com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.authorize(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:76)
    at com.azinky.CalendarSample.authorize(CalendarSample.java:95)
    at com.azinky.CalendarSample.main(CalendarSample.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
```

Do I need to have jetty installed on my machine in order to run this example? (The documentation doesn't say I need to)

This is my full classpath

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/google-api-client-1.19.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/google-oauth-client-1.19.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/google-http-client-1.19.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/jsr305-1.3.9.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/google-api-services-calendar-v3-rev92-1.19.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/google-http-client-jackson2-1.19.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/google-oauth-client-jetty-1.19.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/google-oauth-client-java6-1.19.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/jackson-core-2.1.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/jetty-6.1.26.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `org.mortbay.jetty.jar` for the first class and `javax.servlet.jar` for the second class.

Download it and add it to your classpath or if you use maven, look in the maven repository and add the missing dependecies to your pom.xml.

Comment: I will give that a try. That isn't mentioned anywhere in the dependencies. https://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/wiki/Setup

Comment: This project uses Maven so no manual download should be required

Comment: @KrzysztofWolny in OP's question is nothing that says that he use maven

Comment: @Jens I understood it that he's trying to run examples from https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client and this is a gradle/maven project. Maybe I was wrong...

Comment: @Jens suggestin manual jar manipulation in MVN project is a reason for downvoting the answer for me, yes. I'd remove this downvote but I cannot as I got error that this answer is edited.

Comment: @Jens Im unable un un-downvote your answer because of this I believe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139949/unable-to-undo-downvote. Can you try to make some change so I can try?

Answer (score 2):

Jens's answer is correct, you need some additional jars. Jetty is used to build a quick web server to make the OAuth process smoother for the user. It's not mandatory to use Google APIs, which is why it is not listed in the wiki, but it helps for command line applications.

To better manage your dependencies, I strongly recommend you to use [maven](http://maven.apache.org). Since the test project you link to has a pom.xml file to describe its dependencies, it will be much easier to build the project with Maven.

If you use Eclipse, you can tell maven to build a project for eclipse by running the following command :

`mvn eclipse:eclipse`

You will find more info [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/).

Eclipse also has several plugins to integrate more easily with Maven, and IntelliJ is directly integrated.